# Hotspot timeout setting in android Nougat

Tags: settings, 7.0-nougat, wifi-hotspot

Where can I find hotspot timeout setting on android Nougat? (I am using Redmi note 4 phone).

I cannot find it anywhere in the hotspot section of settings. Problem is I turn it on and then I forget to turn it off at night. The hotspot keeps running all night and I lose battery for nothing. It would really be bad if it was removed in Nougat :(

I searched for the solution but everyone who asked question related to this want to turn the hotspot timeout off and not on.

Comment: You can, alternatively, use an automation app like MacroDroid or Tasker to turn off the hotspot at a set internal or time or event.